# AJAX Calls to Elasticsearch Causing Memory Leak of XHR Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, elasticsearch, xmlhttprequest

I am currently trying to build a line chart using D3 that loads its data from an Elasticsearch server and, when brushed, re-loads the data according to the new boundaries on the x-axis. This has been implemented, but as the JavaScript code loads and re-loads the data using AJAX requests (through jQuery), the old AJAX requests are kept around and their memory is not being released (as can be seen in the browser inspector). This might be because of the browser's internal references to the XHR objects produced by the AJAX calls, but I am not sure. Below is one of the functions that do the querying (it eventually calls the "minMaxLoaded" callback function in which execution continues that uses the data. I have tried many tactics, such as storing the AJAX calls in variables and later setting them to null, but to no avail. As far as I know, since this is all wrapped in a function, the JavaScript references should disappear after the function completes and the requests should be garbage collected. Anyway, here you go:

```
function queryMinMax(domain, index) {
    var absMin;
    var absMax;

    var minmaxQuery = {
        "aggregations" : {
            "minTime" : {
                "top_hits" : {
                    "size" : 1,
                    "sort" : [ { "timestamp" : { "order" : "asc" } } ]
                }
            },
            "maxTime" : {
                "top_hits" : {
                    "size" : 1,
                    "sort" : [ { "timestamp" : { "order" : "desc" } } ]
                }
            }
        }
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: domain + index + "/_search?search_type=count",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(minmaxQuery),

        success: function(response) {
            absMin = parseDate(response.aggregations.minTime.hits.hits[0]._source["timestamp"]).getTime();
            absMax = parseDate(response.aggregations.maxTime.hits.hits[0]._source["timestamp"]).getTime();
            minMaxLoaded(absMin, absMax);
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried calling `abort()` on the ajax object returning from the `$ajax` call before creating a new one (instead of just setting the reference to null)?

Comment: That didn't seem to change anything. Is it possible that keeping the responses around is just a feature of the Safari Web Console? When I close the web console, do some queries, and re-open it, the responses are gone.

Comment: What makes you think there are memory leaks? Have you inspected your memory and noticed it keeps increasing or it's just a feeling? In all cases, this hasn't much to do with Elasticsearch, I'm afraid.

Comment: The only indication that there could be a memory leak is that Safari shows a list of the responses while the Web Console is open.

Comment: The Web Console would not be of much use if it didn't show the list of responses, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the Safari Web Console keeps track of the responses that are made while it's open. The reason processing time slowed down so much was because of this. If the web console is closed, the issue is gone.